# Replace in their previous place all those substrings extracted with .group() method in their original string after they have been modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, list

how to apply the indicated modification process to each of the substrings extracted from the string called `input_text` with `re.group()` method, and then replace them in the original string `input_text`.

I think I should put a `for` loop that iterates over the lists inside the list called `civil_time_unit_list`

```py
import re

def numerical_time_corrector(input_text):
    hh, mm, am_pm, output = "", "", "", ""

    input_text = re.sub(r"([0-9])h.s.", r"\1 ", input_text)
    input_text = re.sub(r"([0-9])\s*h.s.", r"\1 ", input_text)
    input_text = re.sub(r"([0-9])hs", r"\1 ", input_text)
    input_text = re.sub(r"([0-9])\s*hs", r"\1 ", input_text)

    civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?'
    civil_time_unit_list = re.findall(civil_time_pattern, input_text)
    print(civil_time_unit_list)
    # civil_time_unit_list[list of detected schedules][lists with the 3 elements of each of the schedules]


    #process to be applied to all times detected within the input string and stored in the list
    #-----------------------------------------
    try:
        hh = civil_time_unit_list[0][0]
        if (hh == ""): hh = "00"
    except IndexError: hh = "00"

    try:
        mm = civil_time_unit_list[0][1]
        if (mm == ""): mm = "00"
    except IndexError: mm = "00"

    try:
        am_pm = civil_time_unit_list[0][2]
        if (am_pm == ""): am_pm = "am"
    except IndexError: am_pm = "am"

    if (len(hh) < 2):
        hh = "0" + hh
    if (len(mm) < 2):
        mm = "0" + mm

    output = (hh + ":" + mm + " " + am_pm).strip()
    #-----------------------------------------

    
    #Here the program should replace this new value in the original input string
    #input_text = "" 

    #return input_text #It should return the new input_string with all values replaced
    return output #I am returning the output just to test that it works, since it should return the original string but with the replacements already done.


input_text = "el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 1:00 hs am 1:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5: h.s. pm"

input_text = numerical_time_corrector(input_text)
print(repr(input_text))
```

You can see how it erroneously prints only one of the values to be corrected in the original string, and not the original string with all its corrected values. This is the wrong output:

```
[('23', '30', 'pm'), ('01', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'pm'), ('1', '', 'pm'), ('5', '', 'pm')]
'23:30 pm'
```

And this is the output I really need to get :

```
[('23', '30', 'pm'), ('01', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'pm'), ('1', '', 'pm'), ('5', '', 'pm')]
'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, 00:00 pm, 01:00 pm  05:00 pm'
```

What should I change in my code so that this fix is applied to all the extracted substrings and then replace everything in `input_text` string and then return it from the function and print it to the console?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re


def numerical_time_corrector(input_text):
    civil_time_pattern = r"(\d*):(\d*)\s*(?:h[ .]?s[ .]?)?\s*(a\s*m|p\s*m)?"
    return re.sub(
        civil_time_pattern,
        lambda g: "{:>02}:{:>02} {}".format(
            g[1] or "", g[2] or "", (g[3] or "").replace(" ", "")
        ),
        input_text,
    )


input_text = "el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 1:00 hs am 1:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5: h.s. pm"

input_text = numerical_time_corrector(input_text)
print(repr(input_text))
```

Prints:

```
'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, 00:00 pm, 01:00 pm  05:00 pm'
```

Comment: It's a good solution, the only problem is that having the code designed the way I put it together allows me to easily add intermediate functions for better text filtering. So what I came up with is a way to iterate the code between `#--------` and `#--------`, but I'm having a hard time with it

Comment: whereas I have the **list of lists** containing `[('23', '30', 'pm'), ('01', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'pm'), ('1', '', 'pm'), ('5', '', 'pm')]`, I think I could go one by one elements inside the list, and then create a dictionary, for example `{ ('5', '', 'pm'):('05', '00', 'pm') }`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this in a two step `re.sub()` using PyPi's regex module. For example:

```
import regex as re

input_text = 'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 1:00 hs am 1:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5: h.s. pm'
output_text = re.sub(r'(?:(?<!\d)(?=\d?:)|(?<!\d)(:)|(?<=:)(?!\d)|(?<=:\d?)(\D))', r'0\1\2', input_text)
output_text = re.sub(r'(\d\d:\d\d)(?:\s*h\.?s\.?)?(\s[ap])\h*(m)', r'\1\2\3', output_text)

print(output_text)
```

Prints:

```
el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, 00:00 pm, 01:00 pm  05:00 pm
```

Comment: mmm it is a good option although the issue is that having the code in the way that I put it gives you more freedom to add more functions. Can you think of a way to iterate what the code enclosed between `#-------` and `#-------` does?

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez, maybe possible if you use `re.finditer()`. However maybe it's not as flexible if you like since I'm formatting the times through the actual regex pattern and substitutions.

Comment: having the list of lists containing `[('23', '30', 'pm'), ('01', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'am'), ('1', '00', 'pm'), ('1', '', 'pm'), ('5', '', 'pm')]`, I think I could go one by one elements inside the list, and then create a dictionary, for example `{ ('5', '', 'pm'):('05', '00', 'pm') }`

Comment: Then I'd suggest something like `for el in re.finditer(r'(\d{0,2}):(\d{0,2})(?:\s*h\.?s\.?)?(\s*[ap])\s*(m)', input_text):`. You'll have a bunch of capture groups per el to call. See this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmDelu/1). For example `el.group(0)` will get you the whole match, `el.group(1)` the first two digits. etc. The `re.finditer` object also contains a span of each match. GL

Comment: I would not give importance to the `"hs"` since you can eliminate them before. How to use the for to have the 3 elements **[hh, mm, am or pm]** extracted?